# Adding new Account: Failed to authenticate with Google, please try again later

Tags: safari, keychain, gmail, accounts, google

I am trying to add a new google account in internet accounts in Mac. I get this error.

I already tried 2 ways I found from google.

1. Open the application "Keychain Access"
2. Look for application passwords containing the words "gmail" or "google"
3. Remove all the entries you find and reboot
4. Authenticate or re-add your Google

my system:
MacOS Catalina, 10.15.7, Macbook pro.
Safari Version 14.0.2 (15610.3.7.1.10, 15610

Where are the failure logs when a sign in fails so I can fix this without talking to google support?

Comment: Hi, I’ve cut a ton of vague words from this. Your details are clear and let’s see if someone knows where a failure is logged. You can avoid all the keychain by making a new user account on the Mac. What one item do you want to enable first in internet accounts? Mail or calendar or something else?

Comment: @bmike you removed the 2 and 3ed ways people suggested I tried.

Comment: @bmike, both mail, calendar, or anything else, never get to choose, can't even connect. when we connect then we can select from the list.

Comment: Feel free to roll back my change or add it in. I prefer to add any failed answers as an answer, then people won’t answer or comment them. Good luck. In the end, you will need support or to expose the error logs. This works out of the box for most people I checked with this morning.